# Is there a transfinite version of Post's Theorem?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Let $\emptyset^{(n)}$ denote the $n$th Turing jump of the empty set. [Post's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem) states:

> A set $B$ is $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ if and only if $B$ is recursively enumerable by an oracle Turing machine with an oracle for $\emptyset^{(n)}$, that is, if and only if $B$ is $\Sigma^{0,\emptyset^{(n)}}_{1}$.

This is a very powerful correspondence and I would like to use it or something similar in my work on hyperarithmetic sets. Is there a generalization of Post's theorem that also describes infinitely iterated Turing jumps, i.e. where we replace $n$ by a computable ordinal $\alpha < \omega_1^{CK}$? For example, can a turing machine with an oracle for $\emptyset^{(\omega^2)}$ recursively enumerate the elements of $\Sigma^{0}_{\omega^2+1}$ and is this a sufficient characterization of that classification, or is such a statement out of reach for some reason?

Comment: (Disclaimer: I had also asked this on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4736506/is-there-a-transfinite-version-of-posts-theorem) but no one could answer me there.)

Comment: What is your definition of $\Sigma^{0}_{\alpha}$ for infinite $\alpha$?

Comment: (This may not be a full answer) A similar result appears in (Ash, Knight, *Computable Structures and the Hyperarithmetical Hierarchy*, Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics v. 144, 2000). It is in reverse relative to this question, first $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ is defined as the class of relations c.e. in $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$, remarking that there is an offset of one compared to the arithmetical hierarchy for finite $\alpha$, so $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ corresponds to $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$ instead. Then $\Sigma_\alpha$ is defined in terms of infinitary $L_{\omega_1\omega}$-formulae.

Comment: $\Sigma_\alpha$ behaves nicely as a normal form theorem is proven. A class of "recursive $\Sigma_\alpha$ formulae" are introduced where the countable conjunctions/disjunctions in the buildup of the formula are required to be over c.e. sets of formulae. Theorem 7.5 is Post-like: letting $\mathcal A$ of the theorem be the standard model of 1st-order Peano arithmetic, it states that a computable $\Sigma_\alpha$ formula defines a $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ (i.e. r.e. in $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$) set on $\mathcal A$. I am not sure if the converse follows from any result in the book.

Comment: @AliEnayat I think the natural extension typically used is to define $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ in terms of [infinitary first-order formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitary_logic). For example, for some infinite group, a formula of the type $ \bigwedge\limits_{n\in\mathbb N} \exists y (y \ast y \ldots \ast y) = x $ (with $\ast$ repeated $n$ times) is $\Sigma^0_\omega$.

Comment: If you define $\Sigma_\alpha^0$ in terms of infinitary logic, isn't *every* subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ simply $\Delta^0$ by virtue of the formula $\bigvee_{n\in S} m=n$ (with no quantifiers)? What **exactly** do you mean by a $\Sigma_\alpha^0$ set? (Also, are we indeed talking about subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, or something else?)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Yes, we are talking about subsets of $\mathbb N$. Intuitively, a set is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ if it is definable by a disjunction of a recursively enumerable set of formulas $\psi_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$, where each $\psi_\beta$ defines a $\Pi^0_\beta$ set. (A more formal definition in terms of codes can be found in the reference linked by C7X in Chapter 7.) Thus, this hierarchy cannot be collapsed (by a similar argument of why the $\Sigma^0_n$ cannot be collapsed, or by looking at examples of specific such sets), if that answers your question.

Comment: @C7X Thank you for the reference, I somehow overlooked this because my definition for $\Sigma_\alpha^0$ was exactly the other way round! (i.e. in terms of the $\Sigma_\alpha$ construction instead of in terms of its complexity of computation, as it is apparently defined here) I see why this might cause confusion. So then only the converse is still open; is $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$ "more" powerful than $\Sigma_\alpha$ in some sense, i.e. can it enumerate the natural numbers satisfying some computable formula $\varphi$ which is not $\Sigma_\alpha$? Why not is also not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: In fact, this "completeness" of $\Sigma_\alpha$ would be very convenient to have. (I will switch to $\Sigma_\alpha$ from here on out to denote the definition in terms of infinitary formulae, in order to avoid ambiguity.)